# How to inject Cache-Control max-age header in Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-headers

I have the following method inside of a Spring controller:

```
public Response myMethod (@PathVariable("id") String id,
        @RequestParam(required = false) Map<String, Object> queryString,
        @RequestHeader(value = HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, required = false) String acceptHeader,
        @RequestHeader(value = HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, required = false, defaultValue = 1) String expiration,
        @RequestHeader(value = HttpHeaders.FROM) String appId) {
// ...
}
```

Here I'm extracting the whole Cache Control header with `@RequestHeader`. Is there a way to only get the `max-age` part either through injection or with further parsing with a dedicated Spring class? Or do I have to do it manually?

Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised there's no parser for the request cache-control header to be found. RFC 7234 allows for any order of directives, case-insensitive, and potentially quoted. Not something you'd want to parse yourself in every project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably define a class, eg: `CacheControlMaxAge`, and then a `Converter<HttpRequest, CacheControlMaxAge>`, and finally declare your parameter as 
a `CacheControlMaxAge`

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CacheControlMaxAge {
  private final int maxAge;
}

@Component
public class CacheControlMaxAgeConverter implements Converter<HttpRequest, CacheControlMaxAge> {

  public CacheControlMaxAge convert(HttpRequest request) {
    // todo: extract stuff from request
    return new CacheControlMaxAge(...);
  }
}

public Response blah(..., CacheControlMaxAge cacheControl) { ... }
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out, but I wanted to check if there's something out-of-the-box before building my own solution

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in Spring (or Boot) to handle this specifically. There may be better representations that already exist, such as `org.springframework.http.CacheControl`, but I don't see anything to specifically enable using it as a parameter (eg: I found no converters when I just looked now)